# Why did my chicken fingers not brown?

Tags: baking, breading

I used a boxed breading that called for dipping chicken in egg and milk then rolling in breading.  The chicken fingers still look kind of white with noticeable flour left on them after baking.  I did use parchment.  Is that why??

Answer (score 5):

Try either a higher oven temperature or more time. Probably higher temperature, unless your chicken was undercooked. Browning occurs above 212F (the boiling point of water), so it won't start until the moisture (eggs and milk) has cooked off of the outside of the chicken.

You may also want to let the milk/egg mixture drip off of the chicken a little (so it isn't too thick) before rolling in the breading.

Comment: Thank you Steve.  I was baking at 425; next time I will go up to 450.  Maybe that will help.  I did let the mixture drip off before rolling. Maybe not enough? Also, I will not use parchment to see if that helps too.

Comment: If you have an oil sprayer, a light mist of olive oil will help. Part of your problem is that the coating dried out and did not brown. This is especially true for flour -- hence the white dust on good artisan bread. A light mist of oil will allow it to brown more evenly.  I know baking is to avoid the oil from frying, but a light mist adds little fat and vastly improves the result.